# Failed to start saned.service: Unit saned.service is masked

Tags: server, services

I'm trying to set up a wireless scanning server.
I'm following this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaneDaemonTutorial but I'm having issues at the time to run `sudo service saned restart` where I get

> Failed to start saned.service: Unit saned.service is masked.

I have even tried to do `systemctl unmask saned.service && systemctl start saned.service`but I stills echoes the same error.

Thanks

Comment: Same probkem I am running 16.04 64bit and cannot unmask saned service either.

Answer (score 5):

I am not expert about systemd internal workings, but I was able to connect to scanner in this setup:

```
computer_A  ---network--->  computer_B with SANE  ---USB---  scanner
```

after running this (on computer_B):

```
sudo systemctl start saned.socket
```

It is probably the right way of doing it, judging by description here:
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159462/what-is-systemds-target-service-and-socket

And to make it start automatically on startup:

```
sudo systemctl enable saned.socket
```

Comment: I was trying to get a PDF scanning program that depends on saned to work.  This allowed the program to find the scanner.  Thank you!

Comment: That's not what a network scanner means. A network scanner stands alone for scanning service.

Answer (score 1):

I copy some answers from this page:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1577137

Post number 13:

> I just received some updates:
>
> libudev1 (229-4ubuntu5) to 229-4ubuntu6
> libudev1:i386 (229-4ubuntu5) to 229-4ubuntu6 
> python3-urllib3 (1.13.1-2) to 1.13.1-2ubuntu0.16.04.1 
> systemd (229-4ubuntu5) to 229-4ubuntu6
> systemd-sysv (229-4ubuntu5) to 229-4ubuntu6
> udev (229-4ubuntu5) to 229-4ubuntu6
>
> Xsane just works fine now (without any configuration). It might be
> that the two extra config-files in /etc/systemd/system (saned.socket
> and saned@.service) are still needed. So I will do some more testing
> before celebrating :)

And post number 18:

> While the systemd related updates fixed sane again as I could find the
> pixma scanner again... However, it turned out to be a scanner from the
> office downstairs (lol, saves me some electricity but I am not sure
> whether they would be happy with that ;) ).
>
> To find my own scanner (pixma MG5700 series) I had to upgrade to
> sane-backends-1.0.26 (from 1.0.25). I added a ppa to my sources.list
> to do this the easy way:
> deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rolfbensch/sane-git/ubuntu xenial main
>
> This version works like a charm.
>
> Anyway, I am clueless about what the systemd fixed but it did it.

It might be useful to read all the posts because that will explain why I initially added saned.socket to /etc/systemd/system but this is no longer needed.