# saned.service Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad) Active: inactive (dead) Needed for shared Scanner

Tags: networking, server, scanner, sane, xsane

This is not a duplicate of
"How to map network scanner"
at
[How to map network scanner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/200915/how-to-map-network-scanner)

It does not even mention this error message.

```
● saned.service  
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)  
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

- I have a working USB scanner on this computer.
- I need saned to be working [Not bad or hidden] so I can access it from another Ubuntu 18.04.1 computer.
- Ubuntu 18.04.1 Exclusively on Both computers and updated within the last 24 hours
- Both are HP:

  - This one an HP 110-220z with an attached HP Office Jet Pro 6830 all-in-one Scanner printer.
  - The one I want to access the Scanner from is a HP Envyt 1200
- XSane produces scanned images from the scanner.

I have followed all the steps in
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaneDaemonTutorial

and

[Failed to start saned.service: Unit saned.service is masked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762702/failed-to-start-saned-service-unit-saned-service-is-masked)

including adding
 ## Access list
192.168.0.0/24
to
/etc/sane.d/saned.conf:

up to the point where I get

```
● saned.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

After doing the following I Rebooted
and got the same as above.

#### Where and What next?

### This is what I have done

**Terminal**

[Have removed the password request lines and Computer name strings for clarity]

```
~$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/saned.socket
~$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/saned@.service
~$ sudo nano /etc/default/saned
~$ sudo nano /etc/sane.d/saned.conf
~$ sudo systemctl enable saned.socket
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/saned.socket → /etc/systemd/system/saned.socket.
~$ sudo systemctl start saned.socket
~$ systemctl status saned.socket
● saned.socket - saned incoming socket
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/saned.socket; enabled; vendor preset: ena
   Active: active (listening) since Fri 2019-03-01 19:31:08 EST; 16s ago
   Listen: [::]:6566 (Stream)
 Accepted: 0; Connected: 0
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/saned.socket

Mar 01 19:31:08 anne-110-220z systemd[1]: Listening on saned incoming socket.

~$ sudo service saned restart 
Failed to restart saned.service: Unit saned.service is masked.
~$ sudo systemctl start saned.socket
~$ sudo systemctl enable saned.socket
~$ sudo service saned status 
● saned.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
~$ sudo systemctl start saned.socket
~$ sudo service saned status
● saned.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
~$ sudo apt-get updat
E: Invalid operation updat
~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Get:5 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease [2,591 B]            
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [270 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [204 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [204 B]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [126 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [123 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [20.8 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [12.2 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [45.2 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [531 kB]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [457 kB]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [278 kB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [66.7 kB]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [123 kB]
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [737 kB]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [728 kB]
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [202 kB]
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [186 kB]
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [339 kB]
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,352 B]
Get:27 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable/non-free i386 Packages [1,820 B]
Get:28 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable/non-free amd64 Packages [1,818 B]
Fetched 4,720 kB in 4s (1,238 kB/s) 
Reading package lists... Done
~$ sudo service saned status
● saned.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
~$ sudo systemctl start saned.socket
~$ sudo service saned status
● saned.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rolfbensch/sane-release

 Ubuntu SANE packages from SANE Stable Source (https://alioth.debian.org/frs/?group_id=30186).

Please send scanner related questions to the SANE mailing list <email address hidden>.

If you need the more recent scanner driver from git, you can use my other PPA: https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-release
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.
Hit:1 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease       
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rolfbensch/sane-release/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rolfbensch/sane-release/ubuntu bionic Release  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                                 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/rolfbensch/sane-release/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
anne@anne-110-220z:~$ sudo service saned status
● saned.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
anne@anne-110-220z:~$ sudo systemctl start saned.socket
anne@anne-110-220z:~$ sudo service saned status
● saned.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
~$
```

**/etc/saned/saned.conf**
*as revised and saved*

```
# saned.conf
# Configuration for the saned daemon

## Daemon options
# Port range for the data connection. Choose a range inside [1024 - 65535].
# Avoid specifying too large a range, for performance reasons.
#
# ONLY use this if your saned server is sitting behind a firewall. If your
# firewall is a Linux machine, we strongly recommend using the
# Netfilter nf_conntrack_sane connection tracking module instead.
#
# data_portrange = 10000 - 10100


## Access list
192.168.0.0/24
# A list of host names, IP addresses or IP subnets (CIDR notation) that
# are permitted to use local SANE devices. IPv6 addresses must be enclosed
# in brackets, and should always be specified in their compressed form.
#
# The hostname matching is not case-sensitive.

#scan-client.somedomain.firm
#192.168.0.1
#192.168.0.1/29
#[2001:db8:185e::42:12]
#[2001:db8:185e::42:12]/64

# NOTE: /etc/inetd.conf (or /etc/xinetd.conf) and
# /etc/services must also be properly configured to start
# the saned daemon as documented in saned(8), services(4)
# and inetd.conf(4) (or xinetd.conf(5)).
```

**/etc/default/saned**
*As edited and saved.*

```
# Defaults for the saned initscript, from sane-utils

# To enable under systemd please read README.Debian
# Set to yes to start saned under SysV
RUN=yes

# Set to the user saned should run as
RUN_AS_USER=saned
```

**/etc/hosts.allow**
*As edited and saved.*

```
# /etc/hosts.allow: list of hosts that are allowed to access the system.
#                   See the manual pages hosts_access(5) and hosts_options(5).
#
# Example:    ALL: LOCAL @some_netgroup
#             ALL: .foobar.edu EXCEPT terminalserver.foobar.edu
#
# If you're going to protect the portmapper use the name "rpcbind" for the
# daemon name. See rpcbind(8) and rpc.mountd(8) for further information.
#
saned  192.168.0
```

Shut all down
Rebooted

re-ran

```
~$ sudo service saned status
[sudo] password for anne: 
● saned.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Noticed this note

```
# NOTE: /etc/inetd.conf (or /etc/xinetd.conf) and
# /etc/services must also be properly configured to start
# the saned daemon as documented in saned(8), services(4)
# and inetd.conf(4) (or xinetd.conf(5)).
```

Tried reading
but only found a confusing array of what I could do.

*Not what I should do to inetd.conf (or /etc/xinetd.conf) and services!* to properly configure them for "saned.service" to work_

### /etc/services does contain:##

```
    sane-port          6566/tcp      # SANE network scanner daemon
```

### /etc/inetd.conf does not exist, should it?##

### It is not offered in Ubuntu software.##

What is used instead for this entry in inetd.conf?

```
    sane-port  stream  tcp  nowait  saned.saned  /usr/local/sbin/saned saned
```

or, if your system is using tcpd, a line like this:

```
    sane-port  stream  tcp  nowait  saned.saned  /usr/local/sbin/tcpd saned
```

### If it is needed How do I find out which of these my system is using

### /etc/xinetd does not exist. Should it?##

### It is not offered in Ubuntu software.

What is used instead for this entry in xinetd?

Your /etc/xinetd.conf should contain a block like this:

```
                service sane-port  
                {  
                  socket_type = stream  
                  server = /usr/local/sbin/saned  
                  protocol = tcp  
                  user = saned  
                  group = saned  
                  wait = no  
                  disable = no  
                }
```

None of the suggested questions below on this page seem relevant.

#### What do I do now?

Comment: I understand from reading that xinetd can be used instead of inetd. Some suggested that neither is presumed needed in say Ubuntu 18.04.  But they were not speaking specifically about inetd in relation to sane. But no one I have read yet specifically states it is Still Required. I do not want to be adding things not offered in Ubuntu Software if that poses a risk.